# Anonymous lambdas directly referring to themselves

Tags: scheme, racket

Does  Scheme or do any dialects of scheme  have a kind of "self" operator so that anonymous lambdas can recur on themselves without doing something like a Y-combinator or being named in a letrec etc.

Something like:

```
(lambda (n)
   (cond
     ((= n 0) 1)
     (else (* n (self (- n 1)))))))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The trouble with the "current lambda" approach is that Scheme has *many* hidden lambdas. For example:

- All the `let` forms (including `let*`, `letrec`, and named `let`)
- `do` (which expands to a named `let`)
- `delay`, `lazy`, `receive`, etc.

To require the programmer to know what the innermost lambda is would break encapsulation, in that you'd have to know where all the hidden lambdas are, and macro writers can no longer use lambdas as a way to create a new scope.

All-round lose, if you ask me.

Comment: Hear, hear.  Note that this is also a problem with "return" as it appears in most languages (Java, C, etc.).

Comment: I do believe that technically, you could make the `self` identifier lexical with regard to the lambda form.  You can even do it yourself if you have `syntax-case`.  I agree anyway, though.  Explicit names are generally preferable to anaphoric ones.

Comment: @Matthias: Indeed, "can" and "should" are totally different, especially in this context. ;-) I was addressing why providing a `self` by default is a terrible idea, in general.

Answer (score 6):

There is a tradition of writing “anaphoric” macros that define special names in the lexical scope of their bodies.  Using `syntax-case`, you can write such a macro on top of `letrec` and `lambda`.  Note that the definition below is as hygienic as possible considering the specification (in particular, invisible uses of `alambda` will not shadow `self`).

```
;; Define a version of lambda that binds the
;; anaphoric variable “self” to the function
;; being defined.
;;
;; Note the use of datum->syntax to specify the
;; scope of the anaphoric identifier. 
(define-syntax alambda
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(alambda lambda-list . body)
       (with-syntax ([name (datum->syntax #'alambda 'self)])
         #'(letrec ([name (lambda lambda-list . body)])
             name))])))

;; We can define let in terms of alambda as usual.
(define-syntax let/alambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ ((var val) ...) . body)
     ((alambda (var ...) . body) val ...)]))

;; The let/alambda macro does not shadow the outer
;; alambda's anaphoric variable, which is lexical
;; with regard to the alambda form.
((alambda (n)
   (if (zero? n)
       1
       (let/alambda ([n-1 (- n 1)])
         (* (self n-1) n))))
 10)
;=> 3628800
```

Most people avoid anaphoric operators since they make the structure of the code less recognizable.  In addition, refactoring can introduce problems rather easily.  (Consider what happens when you wrap the `let/alambda` form in the factorial function above in another `alambda` form.  It's easy to overlook uses of `self`, especially if you're not reminded of it being relevant by having to type it explicitly.)  It is therefore generally preferable to use explicit names.  A “labeled” version of `lambda` that allows this can be defined using a simple `syntax-rules` macro:

```
;; Define a version of lambda that allows the
;; user to specifiy a name for the function
;; being defined.
(define-syntax llambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ name lambda-list . body)
     (letrec ([name (lambda lambda-list . body)])
       name)]))

;; The factorial function can be expressed
;; using llambda.
((llambda fac (n)
   (if (zero? n)
       1
       (* (fac (- n 1)) n)))
 10)
;=> 3628800
```

Comment: Your `llambda` is almost identical to [SRFI 31](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html)'s `rec`, and the latter is the usual name for the construct. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Ah, interesting.  I ought to browse the SRFI list more often. ;)  `rec` even seems to be more general; in fact, it looks like a generalization of ancient LISP's `label` operator (which was actually the first thing that came to mind when I read the OP's question).

Comment: Two things.  First, especially in the Racket context there is a [better way](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2008/02/dirty-looking-hygiene.html) to do this.  Second, the problem with anaphoric macros that you're referring to (nested scope for the implicit name) is not the biggest problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way using continuations to have anonymous lambdas call themselves and then using Racket macros to disguise the syntax so the anonymous lambda appears to have a "self" operator.  I don't know if this solution is possible in other versions of Scheme since it depends on the Call-with-composable-continuation function of racket and the Macro to hide the syntax uses syntax parameters.

The basic idea is this, illustrated with the factorial function.

```
( (lambda (n)
     (call-with-values 
       (lambda () (call-with-composable-continuation  
                        (lambda (k) (values k n))))
     (lambda (k n)
        (cond 
          [(= 0 n) 1]
          [else (* n (k k (- n 1)))])))) 5)
```

The continuation k is the call to the anonymous factorial function, which takes two arguments, the first being the continuation itself. So that when in the body we execute (k k N) that is equivalent to the anonymous function calling itself (in the same way that a recursive named lambda would do).

We then disguise the underlying form with a macro.  Rackets syntax-parameters allow the transformation of (self ARGS ...) to (k k ARGS ... )

so we can have:

```
 ((lambda-with-self (n)
    (cond 
      [(= 0 n) 0]
      [(= 1 n) 1]
      [else (* n (self (- n 1)))])) 5)
```

The complete Racket program to do this is:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/stxparam) ;required for syntax-parameters
(  define-syntax-parameter self (λ (stx) (raise-syntax-error #f "not in  `lambda-with-self'" stx)))

(define-syntax-rule
(lambda-with-self (ARG ... ) BODY ...) 
 (lambda (ARG ...)
   (call-with-values 
    (lambda ()(call/comp (lambda (k) (values k ARG ...))))
    (lambda (k ARG ...)
      (syntax-parameterize ([self (syntax-rules ( )[(self ARG ...) (k k ARG ...)])])
    BODY ...)))))
;Example using factorial function
((lambda-with-self (n)
      (cond 
        [(= 0 n) 0]
        [(= 1 n) 1]
        [else (* n (self (- n 1)))])) 5)
```

This also answers my previous question about the differences between the different kinds of continuations.
    [Different kinds of continuations in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607355/different-kinds-of-continuations-in-racket)

This only works because unlike call-with-current-continuation, call-with-composable-continuation doesn't abort back to a continuation prompt but invokes the continuation at the place it was invoked.

Comment: Looking over the original question you're right, but I saw this as a way to simulate or add a 'self" operator to a lambda.  It just seemed a cool way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Racket supports [SRFI-31](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html), which provides a macro named `rec` for making lambdas that can call themselves. Basic example:

```
#lang racket/base

(require srfi/31)

((rec (self n)
   (cond
     ((= n 0) 1)
     (else (* n (self (- n 1))))))
 5) ; => 120
```