# Different kinds of continuations in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations

Can someone give a relatively simple example of the differences in Racket between `call-with-composable-continuation` and `call-with-current-continuation`.

I've worked through the examples in the [Racket Guide 10.3](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Continuations.html) of `call-with-composable-continuation`, and the examples of `call-with-current-continuation` in The Scheme Programming language section 3.3  but I'm not clear on the difference.

Could someone give an example where they would give different results in the same context.

Comment: You might like Eli Barzilay's very accessible explanation of the various sorts of continuations: http://tmp.barzilay.org/cont.txt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very thorough explanation is found in the paper "Adding Delimited and Composable Control to a Production Programming Environment" by Flatt, Yu, Findler and Felleisen.

http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/icfp07-fyff.pdf